# Running a grep command using java Runtime api

Tags: java, unix, grep, runtime

I need to grep some text inside a list of files(file count is huge) in unix server and then list the file name in a web gui. So I decided best way to achieve this is by writing a unix command executer using Runtime.getRuntime().
Works fine for most of the unix command but facing this strange grep issue.

First of all code:

```
public class UnixCommandExecutor {

    private static StringBuffer output = new StringBuffer();

    public static String exec(String command) throws Exception{
        Process process = null;
        process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
        BufferedReader stdErr = getBufferedReader(process.getErrorStream());
        BufferedReader stdIn = getBufferedReader(process.getInputStream());
        StringBuffer data = extractData(stdErr);
        if (data.length() >= 1) {
            System.out.println("Error: " +data.toString());
            throw new Exception(data.toString());
        }
        data = extractData(stdIn);
        if (data.length() >= 1) {
            output = data;
            System.out.println("Output: " +data.toString());
        }
        return output.toString();
    }

    private static BufferedReader getBufferedReader(InputStream stream) {
        InputStreamReader inReader = new InputStreamReader(stream);
        BufferedReader buffReader = new BufferedReader(inReader);
        return buffReader;
    }

    private static StringBuffer extractData(BufferedReader reader)
            throws IOException {
        StringBuffer data = new StringBuffer();
        String s = "";
        while ((s = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            data.append(s + "\n");
        }
        return data;
    }

    public StringBuffer getOutput() {
        return output;
    }
}
```

Now the call would be something like this: 
String output = exec("find . -name blah"); 
This works fine and the result is perfect. Or any other unix command executes and provides the result properly.

But when grep command is used it gives a strange error:
String output = exec("grep -l executor *");

`Error: grep: *: No such file or directory`

This is strange, since if I run this command directly on unix it gives the desired result.
Also tried giving the file path something like,
String output = exec("grep -l executor /file/path/*"); 
even then the error is:

`Error: grep: /file/path/*: No such file or directory`

Any ideas? or any other better way to solve this?
Any suggestion is welcome.

Comment: ok.. i got this to work. Basically i needed two thing to make it to work. First use `/bin/sh -c` and secondly use `Runtime.exec(String[])` api. So overall my method call now looks like `String[] commands = new String[]{"/bin/sh","-c","grep -l executor *"}; exec(commands);` Works just fine and result is displayed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `*` is interpreted by the shell, not `grep` itself. So it doesn't work if you start `grep` from your Java program.

You can use `grep` with `-r` to make it search recursively, then use `.` for the current directory:

```
grep -lr executor .
```

To simulate the behaviour of the shell, just replace `*` with a space separated list of all files in the folder you want to search in. You can get the list of all files with:

```
StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();

for (File f : new File("your folder").listFiles()) {
    if (f.isFile()) {
        str.append(' ').append(f.getPath());
    }
}
```

Now just replace the `*` with the result of `str.toString()`.

Comment: I guess you are bang on that * is interprestted by shell and thats why I am facing this problem. But to use grep `.` and recursivly is expensive and impacts on performance as it will include unwanted files to grep whic I would like to avoid. On other note, what would be the best way to tackle * in grep? any ideas?